How to paste text into VirtualBox without installing anything?
Running Ubuntu VM as guest without installing (Try Ubuntu using ISO image) on an Ubuntu host.
How to paste text from host into guest (basically type it using soft keyboard) with a shortcut, without installing any extensions or guest additions?
